# What else prevents file deletion on OS X beside permissions, ACL, flags or being in use?

Tags: macos, unix, acl, bitdefender

As root (OS X 10.9.5), I cannot delete a file with no flags or ACL entry (at least seemingly), despite having the correct permissions:

```
/Library/LaunchAgents$ whoami
root
/Library/LaunchAgents$ ls -alOe
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin  -  204 Jan 12 22:56 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 66 root  admin  - 2244 May  9 15:26 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  -  690 May  4  2016 com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents$ chmod -N com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents$ chflags 0 com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents$ rm com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist
rm: com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist: Permission denied
/Library/LaunchAgents$
```

The ACL entry above pertains to the /Library folder and shouldn't affect /Library/LaunchAgents. I have successfully moved other items in LaunchAgents while the bitdefender item fails. Have tried doing the above in single user mode as well with the same result.

What am I missing?

The purpose was to remove all traces of BitDefender. Having deleted its main folder where the files referenced in the plist resided, no daemons are running. I am however puzzled as to how this is possible.

Comment: The file is owned by root - how about just a simple `sudo rm`?

Comment: Permission denied. The commands I posted were run as root (see whoami)

Comment: Despite the runnable files not being there, if `launchctl` thought it should start the BitDefender daemon, it may not let you `rm` the file. Try `launchctl list`; if BitDefender shows up, `launchctl unload com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist` and then an `rm` should probably get it.

Comment: I have tried unloading from launchctl before deleting to no avail. Subsequently did `launchctl list` and there was nothing there that I recognized. Also I believe in single user mode the daemons are not launched.

Comment: Strangely enough a `.plist~` file that got created when I opened the file with `emacs` cannot be deleted either, which points toward it having inherited something that prevents deletion.

Comment: Maybe try `chmod -I ...` (capital i), which removes inherited ACL's, and/or `chmod -i ...`, which would also remove the inherited bit.

Comment: Did not work: `/Library/LaunchAgents$ chmod -I com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist
chmod: No ACL currently associated with file 'com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist'
chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist': Operation not permitted` Same answer for `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a **kext** that protects the file (the antivirus trying to "defend" itself), but `sudo kextunload <name>` (see the kexts with `kextstat | grep -v apple`) should work... Or, even better, first eliminate the daemon (vs agent) that controls it with `sudo launchctl remove <name>` (see the daemons with `sudo launchctl list | grep -v apple`).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's taking advantage of OSX's [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) model, but you don't need to worry about that.

They ship an uninstaller, it's just not very well documented. Here's how you get to it:

> Open finder -> Utilities -> BitDefender Uninstaller.

Comment: I did try to run the uninstaller first, but it failed. The problem above occurred when I subsequently removed the files manually. I am running OS X Mavericks which it seems does not have system integrity protection. Checking the FreeBSD _securelevel_ with `sysctl -n kern.securelevel` returns 0.